# Searching Twice gives Object reference null

Tags: vb.net, api, search, nullreferenceexception, google-search-api

'Button1

```
Dim ex1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ex1_sub)

Dim ex2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ex2_sub)

ex1.Start()
ex2.Start()
```

'End Sub

```
Sub ex1_sub()

Dim result_ex1 As IWebResult

Dim client_ex1 As New GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com")

Dim results_ex1 As IList(Of IWebResult) = client_ex1.Search("love", 2)

For Each result_ex1 In results_ex1
MsgBox(result_ex1.Title)
Next

End Sub


Sub ex2_sub()
Dim result_ex2 As IWebResult

Dim client_ex2 As New GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com")

Dim results_ex2 As IList(Of IWebResult) = client_ex2.Search("hate", 2)

For Each result_ex2 In results_ex2
MsgBox(result_ex2.Title)
Next

End Sub
```

It points either to results_ex2 or results_ex1 and tells me 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How could I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't guarantee that `client_ex1.Search()` or `client_ex2.Search()` always return a value, do simple check after function call to avoid [Null reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). For example :

```
.......
Dim results_ex2 As IList(Of IWebResult) = client_ex2.Search("hate", 2)
If results_ex2 Is Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("API returns no result")
Else
    For Each result_ex2 In results_ex2
        MsgBox(result_ex2.Title)
    Next
End If
.......
```

Comment: have you applied the same building block for `results_ex1`? In which line you get the error?

Comment: Yes I did , 
I get error in this line
im results_ex2 As IList(Of IWebResult) = client_ex2.Search("hate", 2)

Comment: It seems that `client_ex2` is `Nothing` instead of `results_ex2` that trigger the exception. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I think results_ex2 and results_ex2 both do have Things because If I comment one of threads above the problem will be solved.